# Javascript Text Editor in UIWebView using execCommand

Tags: javascript, colors, uiwebview, font-face

Why can't the following javascript command set the font color in RGB hex used in a UIWebView  html rich text editor ?

Colors in RGB hex are changed to the standard blue, yellow, red, etc, for example:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.execCommand('forecolor', false, '#407ec9')"]];
```

generates in html

```
<font color="#0000ff"> HELLO WORLD </font>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. This is my workaround answer:

```
NSString *color = @"#407ec9";
NSString *text = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '%@')", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<font color=\"%@\">%@</font>", color, text]]];
```

Comment: If possible I would recommend using something other than a deprecated `<font>` tag. `<span style="...">` would be better.

Comment: Maybe if you have contenteditable property to true then it would work

Answer (score 0):

The following works in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Opera, and even Internet Explorer 9:

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.execCommand('forecolor', false, '#407ec9');" value="Change" />
<div contenteditable="true">Test</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M5j8b/

It also works in Mobile Safari in iOS 6.

I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong with your `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` call. I suspect something isn't being escaped properly.

I would try making a simple JavaScript function on the page and call it instead:

```
function foo() {
    document.execCommand('forecolor', false, '#407ec9')
}
```

If that doesn't work, I suspect a different problem.

Comment: Sorry I'm using that JS command in iOS UIWebView. I was trying to simplify my question and have now edited it to properly form the problem in an iOS environment. It seems like an issue with UIKit then.

Comment: Doesn't work. I'm posting a workaround answer. Thanks for your time in helping!

Comment: @chongsj Odd. It should have. There must be something else in your page. Well, glad you figured something